# ScalaTest - testing equality between two floating point arrays with error margin

Tags: scala, floating-point, scalatest

Let's say I have a function that returns a array of doubles. I want to test this function and have calculated the correct value by hand. However since it's floating point numbers, I can't do direct comparisons so is there any sweet syntax by ScalaTest that makes me able to compare double arrays with an epsilion/error margin?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling Doubles in ScalaTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27809423/handling-doubles-in-scalatest)

Comment: @Suma this question is older than the one you linked so that one is a dup of this

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well as I feared there is no nice syntax in ScalaTest for this, and I will accept my own answer with a very basic solution.

```
val Eps = 1e-3 // Our epsilon

val res = testObject.test // Result you want to test.
val expected = Array(...) // Expected returning value.

res.size should be (expected.size)

for (i <- 0 until res.size) res(i) should be (expected(i) +- Eps)
```

As seen, this works. Then you can make it nicer by perhaps defining an implicit method.

Comment: where does the `+-` come from?

Comment: It's in the scalatest library.

Comment: found it in `org.scalactic.Tolerance` but it is added in the scope when using `org.scalatest.Matchers`

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
 import Inspectors._
 import scala.math._

 forExactly(max(a1.size, a2.size), a1.zip(a2)){case (x, y) => x shouldBe (y +- eps)}
```

Or you can provide [custom equality](http://doc.scalatest.org/2.0/index.html#org.scalautils.Equality) (there is a [built-in](http://doc.scalatest.org/2.0/index.html#org.scalautils.TolerantNumerics) one as @Suma sugested)

Comment: It's nice but it's a home made solution, I have already done something similar. You don't know of any ScalaTest syntax for it? Like `a should be (b +- Eps)`?

Comment: Doesn't compile, sorry.

Comment: @dk14: How about commenting before answering this?

Comment: if it doesn't - you can "-1" it or at least explain why. To explain why, leave a comment below this answer.

Comment: Well they are obviously solutions to solving *how* to do this, but it can't be considered any sweet syntax. However I don't think ScalaTest has any such syntax. Thanks @dk14 for the effort though!

Comment: Np. You may ask for such feature here: http://groups.google.com/group/scalatest-users

Comment: It seems to me the TolerantNumerics.tolerantDoubleEquality could be used for personEq. Is there anything missing in it, requiring to implement a custom one?

Comment: this only works on single numbers but not for sequences like `Seq[1.199999] shouldBe Seq[1.2]`. However I can not beleve that there is no built in tolerant matcher for lists of numbers

Comment: @KIC you need to provide an `Equality[List[Double]]`, not just `Equality[Double]`. Also, `should ===` should be used instead of `shouldBe`, since the latter cannot customize equality (I've suggested an edit to this answer).