# Handling Doubles in ScalaTest

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have just started using ScalaTest and I am using the following to compare two Doubles in my spec as follows:

```
  it should "calculate the price" in {
    val x = new X(10,10,12,1000)
    assert(x.price() === 185.92)
  }
```

The spec is passing even though I have put in a wrong value of 185.92 to compare against what the price function is returning (that actually returns 10.23 for the case above). I have other specs where I just compare `Ints` and they work as expected. But the ones involving `Doubles` are passing regardless. Is there another functions besides `assert` I should be using to compare `Doubles`?

EDIT:

```
def price () : Double
```

Comment: Not your actual question, but you shouldn't use `Double` (or any floating-point type) to represent a price. Use `BigDecimal` or a Spire type instead - a type that can perform exact decimal arithmetic anyway.

Comment: Yes, I will be using Spire but I'm just experimenting with ScalaTest at the moment.

Comment: My first theory is that x.price() is returning a type that thinks this instance is equal to Double 185.92. Can you show what type x.price() returns? Also, you can mix in org.scalactic.TypeCheckedEquality, or import org.scalactic.TypeCheckedEquality._ to get a type error if the types don't match up.

Comment: @BillVenners, have added the definition for the `price` function. BTW, I can't fine TypeCheckedEquality. Has it been removed from scalatic?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't compile my comment! I meant TypeCheckedTripleEquals. Given that it looks like it is a Double, assuming you've not got a custom implicit Equality[Double] in scope that is extremely forgiving, it sounds more like your test may not be getting executed at all. Can you add more context? I.e., show the whole test class? If that is OK, I'd ask how you are executing the test and what the output looks like.

Comment: Thanks Bill. ScalaTest is now highlighting the main issue. I mixed in the TypeCheckedTripleEquals and it showed up a type issue with a test just before the one in this post (in the same spec). The return type for the function in that test is `Double` but I was comparing it against an `Int` literal value. So it seems that ScalaTest ignored the tests after the one which had the type mismatch.

Answer (score 25):

It looks to me like you've got an implicit instance of `Equality[Double]` in scope along the lines of `org.scalactic.TolerantNumerics`, for which the documentation is [here](http://doc.scalatest.org/2.2.1/index.html#org.scalactic.TolerantNumerics).

The example from the doc is:

```
implicit val doubleEquality = TolerantNumerics.tolerantDoubleEquality(0.01)
```

But it looks like somebody has instantiated it with a really big tolerance value in your case.

You may also consider trying explicit tolerance by using `+-`:

```
assert(x.price() === 185.92 +- 0.01)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can simply do `actual shouldBe (expected +- tolerance)` if using `FlatSpec`; other specs have similar matchers instead of `shouldBe`. It gives better messages in case of failures than `assert`, and the code is consistent with the other tests.