# ScalaTest - check for "almost equal" for floats and objects containing floats

Tags: scala, floating-point, scalatest

While writing tests for operations with floats or objects containing floats (like vectors or matrices), I often want to test not for equality, but for "almost equal" (difference allowed to be some epsilon).

When using [ScalaTest FunSuite](http://doc.scalatest.org/1.3/org/scalatest/FunSuite.html), one normally writes `assert(xxx == yyy)`. With floats and likes I can write `assert(math.abs(xxx - yyy)<epsilon)`, but then I do not get the nice feature of the [ScalaTest assert macro](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_assertions) of being reported the compared values as a part of the failure message.

How can I  perform testing of float "almost equality" in ScalaTest, so that when the test fails, the values are written as a part of the failure message?

Test example:

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

class FloatTest extends FunSuite {
  test("Testing computations") {
    import math._
    assert(sin(Pi/4)==sqrt(0.5))
    assert(sin(Pi)==0)
  }
}
```

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213930/scalatest-testing-equality-between-two-floating-point-arrays-with-error-margin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213930/scalatest-testing-equality-between-two-floating-point-arrays-with-error-margin)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It can be done using [TolerantNumerics](http://doc.scalatest.org/2.2.4/index.html#org.scalactic.TolerantNumerics) and using `===` instead of `==`.

```
import org.scalactic.TolerantNumerics
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

class FloatTest extends FunSuite {

  val epsilon = 1e-4f

  implicit val doubleEq = TolerantNumerics.tolerantDoubleEquality(epsilon)

  test("Testing computations") {
    import math._
    assert(sin(Pi / 4) === sqrt(0.5))
    assert(sin(Pi) === 0.0)
  }
}
```

For your own types you can define your own subclasses of [Equality[T]](http://doc.scalatest.org/2.2.4/index.html#org.scalactic.Equality).